# Firebase bandwidth usage also when there isn't active devices

Tags: android, firebase

I have a problem with the bandwidth usage of my Firebase account.

I've stored only 79.66 KB but the used bandwidth is 46.41 MB.

I have followed all the general guidelines.

I have two questions:
- When I open the app dashboard, the Data section is shown.
My database is entirely downloaded?

- I have a bandwidth usage also when there is no activity in the "Database Operations per Hour" chart.(And I have not used the dashboard in that period) What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

> When I open the app dashboard, the Data section is shown. My database is entirely downloaded?

It's slightly more involved than a simple "yes".

When you database is small, it is indeed entirely downloaded when you open the Data tab of your Firebase dashboard.

Once your database reaches a certain size, the dashboard switches over to a read-only mode. It then only loads one level of the tree, until you click on a specific node; then it loads the next level.

Comment: Thanks.  Regard my second question? Have you any idea of what draw my bandwidth when there is no devices(or dashboard) active?

Comment: Do you have now an answer for this ? I have the same "issue".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your database is entire downloaded.

Try resetting your firebase account under account info.
If that doesn't work, contact tech support at [firebase-support@google.com](http://mailto:firebase-support@google.com?Subject=Database%20Activity%20Misinformation%20Bug)

Comment: What do you mean with "resetting your firebase account"?